# VMWare Remote Console "Portable" / VMRC

Tags: remote-access, esxi

I need to use VMWare ESXi Vms from a remote location.

I am looking for a desktop tool to access VMWare infrastructure Virtual Machines from a remote computer.

A tool in the same line as the old Microsoft VMRC for the Windows 2005 Virtual Server. Preferably Open Source; better FOSS.

Is there any "Portable" Remote Console (VMRC) 
to access VMs installed in a ESXi Server?

Comment: I am not aware of any OSS VMRC alternatives.  However, Windows VMRC is basically portable if you don't need to connect USB devices from the client to the VM.

Comment: I know the VMWare remote console "https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VMRC801&productId=491" but this is not portable... what i did not know is that MS VMRC protocol is compatible with VMWare VM(s)... ?Are you talking about -->> VMRC from Virtual Server 2005 ??? :)

Comment: If you install Windows VMRC on a computer, then you should be able to just copy the directory and run it on another computer without needing to formally install it.  The only thing that requires the installer are the USB drivers.  That's what I mean by Windows VMRC being mostly portable.

Comment: Thanks james... just to confirm... the VMRC you are talking is the Virtual Server 2005 VMRC ??

Comment: No, I'm talking about VMware VMRC for Windows.  I say "Windows VMRC" to distinguish it from VMware's VMRC for Mac OS X.